# Jquery mobile popup is not firing with requireJS & backboneJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs

I made routing in using the jquery mobile and backboneJS. Now my problem is i have to trigger a popup dynamically from my function.

The code is:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
        'jquerymobile',
        'views/nextview'
], function ($, _, Backbone, JqueryMobile, NextView) {
         'use strict';
        var Collection = '';
        var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

         ......

          renderList: function(tasks){
             $(".results").each(function() {
               $(this).popup("open");
             });
          },


        .......
});
return MyView;
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="results" id="results" data-role="pop_up" data-transition="slidedown"></ul>
```

The HTML contents inside this ul will be populated by another function prior to this.

The problem is, `$(this).popup("open")` function is not firing.

It says `cannot call methods on popup prior to initialization;`

Comment: you can open several popups at the same time, try with one at least. The error means that popup isn't present within the same active page, or it's still not rendered. pls post more details on popup markup and how you append it dynamically.

Comment: I tried calling a single popup window using its id which is already present in the page. it is giving me the same error.

Comment: `data-role=popup` not `pop_up` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/y3L2X/

Comment: @Prabakaran, please ask Omar to submit his answer formally and please mark it as accepted. This way people who would like to help will know that you've found the solution to your problem.

Comment: yes ofcourse. I think, @Omar may saw your comment. Pls post this as answer, then only i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `pop_up` instead of `popup` in `data-role` attribute.

```
<ul class="results" id="results" data-role="popup" data-transition="slidedown">
  <!-- item -->
</ul>
```